Snowflake network rule to send from gmail
I have developed a Streamlit app on streamlit.io that is a form where the app user can choose the email recipient, some other details and then submit.  The form then emails the recipient the other details chosen. This works perfectly.
I'm trying to convert this app to Streamlit in Snowflake because the details are from tables in Snowflake and I want the app the be more secure.
I need to create a network rule so that Snowflake can access the gmail account to send the email from. At the moment I've tried:
create or replace network rule gmail_access
    mode = egress
    type = host_port
    value_list = ('smtp.gmail.com:465')
;

with and without the smtp subdomain and I always get the error:
invalid value '[smtp.gmail.com:465]' for property 'VALUE_LIST'
I can't use system$send_email because the recipients are not on the allowed list and also I'm not receiving any emails when I am on the allowed list (I think the Snowflake SPF or DMARC or DKIM records are not correct).
Does anyone know how to get a Streamlit in Snowflake app working to send form details via a gmail account to other recipients?

This seems to be a problem with the VALUE_LIST parameter which is accepting only the port value 443, 80 when setting it with the network rule. This should be brought up with the snowflake team and see if there is a fix for it or a way to use custom port numbers.
